# Carla 0.9.13 Installation Issues

Tags: python, pip, carla

I'm trying to install [CARLA 0.9.13](https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.13/) on Python 3.10. on Windows 8.

I'm following the steps mentioned in [this guide.](https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.13/start_quickstart/)

When I reach [this point](https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.13/start_quickstart/#install-client-library) I'm having troubles with the following piece of instruction.

[Install Client Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4P7d.png)

Specifically with this piece of code:

```
pip3 install carla
```

This always returns the following [error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qnMP.png)

I have used "Package Install" and downloaded the relevant files from Github along with the "Additional Maps".

Please point out where I'm messing up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation Carla as a pip installable package is only available for python versions `2.7, 3.6, 3.7, and 3.8`.

There is a github issue relating to getting it to build on `3.10`.

https://github.com/carla-simulator/carla/issues/5538

But that's for ubuntu not windows. Looks like it'll involve quite a bit of C++ knowledge to make it work.
Only other alternative I can see would be to install python `3.8` and try.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue, I was using Python 3.11, downgrading it to **Python 3.8** solved the issue on Windows 10.
*However, downgrading to Python 3.7 doesn't help.*